# Flutter the difference of two codes about setState()

Tags: flutter

are these codes does the same work?
As far as I understand the setState() notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed, so it does not matter if we pass inside it an argument or not.

```
    Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
        setState(() {
           _counter++;
        });
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirName = directory.path;
    await File('$dir/counter.txt').writeAsString('$_counter');
   }
   _______________________________________________________________
   Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
        _counter++;
        setState(() {          
        });
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final String dirName = directory.path;
    await File('$dir/counter.txt').writeAsString('$_counter');
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does the same thing whether you write `_counter++` inside `setState()` or before it.

```
  setState(() {
     _counter++;
  });
```

Writing as above only makes the code more understandable. Because it is clear to anyone who is looking at the code that we are calling `setState()` here to reflect this `_counter++` change in the UI.

Comment: ohh ok so just for a clean code  thank you for your help